# Linux send packets to multiple destinations on local loopback

Tags: c, linux

I have an application that is essentially a UDP relay server.  When the relay server receives a packet, it echoes it out to multiple relay clients.  Note that all clients will be separate processes on the same machine, and in fact I do not want the packets to leave the machine.  My current methodology is to use the 127.0.0.1 local loopback and keep track of all the relay clients, each of which is listening on a unique UDP port.  Then when a packet comes in, I iterate through the list of clients and copy the packet to each one.
This works OK, but doesn't scale well to the hundreds or even thousands of clients I want to support.  The packet rate is usually slow (1  a second or so), but there can be bursts.  So I'm looking for other options.  Some I've considered:

1) Have all relay clients bind to the same UDP port number.  I've seen conflicting information on this, sometimes saying that all processes will receive the packet and others saying Linux will decide who to give it to using some type of "load balancing" algorithm.

2) Local loopback broadcast.  The server would send to 127.255.255.255.  Again I've seen that this works and that it doesn't work.

3) Multicast. Don't know much about this, but if it is possible to do multicasts isolated to the internal loopback, that might be an option.

I'm writing in C and running on a Debian Linux server.

Any opinions on how best to do this?

Comment: You can test if the lookback broadcast works easily with `nc`. Server: `nc -l -u 9999`, client `echo works | nc -u 127.255.255.255 9999`. It doesn't work on my system.

Comment: MQTT's publish/subscribe paradigm is designed to solve this problem (on a grander scale). I wonder how they solve it?

Comment: I can confirm that (1) doesn't work. With [SO_REUSEPORT](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/) this is very promising, but on macos (I tried) and Linux (according to the link) the kernel decides on one server to give it to. Even trying to have the servers "forward" it on to other servers doesn't work because it's likely to come straight back to the same server. Even using MSG_PEEK doesn't work for the same reasons. Even adding delays after recvfrom doesn't work because the kernel has already decided where the msg is going.

Comment: However, it does work with socat:
`echo -n "TEST" | socat - udp-datagram:127.255.255.255:9999,broadcast`
Perhaps netcat doesn't support broadcasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with #1, have all relay clients bind to the same UDP port number.  Despite comments about Linux deciding which process will get the packet, I found that all of them received every packet.  Perhaps this is a difference between TCP and UDP?  Furthermore, it worked even without the `SO_REUSEPORT` option.  That doesn't make sense to me as it should have returned on error on `bind()`.  Either way, it is working just as I want on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fourth option, `bind` once, and make all the server instances read from the same socket. Only a processes that is blocking on recv (and have nothing to do) may recieve the packet.

```
void
run_child(int fd)
{
  while (1)
    {
      char buff[SIZE];
      recv(fd, buff, ....);    
      do_something(buff);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
   int fd = create_udp_socket();
   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDS; i++)
     {
        pid_t p = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
          {
            run_child(fd);
            _exit();
          }
     }
   wait_for_children_to_exit();
}
```

If your worker processes are not created by forking a single parent, you can send the file descriptor to the workers with `sendmsg(...)` and `SCM_RIGHTS`. (But I would recommend the fork method)